# finding a letter in a string with jquery

Tags: jquery

it looks very basic thing but i could not figure it out.

```
var email = $("input#email").val();
```

how can i check if that `email` variable has `@` letter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or instead of regex, use the correct tool: `indexOf()`

```
var hasAtCharacter = (email.indexOf('@') != -1);
```

Comment: Correct with respect to the question, but a really bad way to validate email addresses -- @@@@@@@@@ is not a valid email address.

Answer (score 3):

Use the string.match() method to check if it matches a regular expression containing @.  You probably want to use a better expression to validate that it's an email address, though.

```
var email = $("input#email").val();
var isEmail = email.match( /@/ );
```

Or you can use a regular expression and the test method.

```
 var email = $('input#email').val();
 var re = new RegExp( '^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$' );
 if (re.test(email)) {
    ...
 }
```

Note - I have no idea if that regex is what you need, you might want to do some research into email validators to see if that's adequate or you want to improve on it.

Alternatively, you could look at using the jQuery [validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin.  It's validation methods include email addresses.

Comment: +1 for your 100k journey, and being a correct answer and all :)

Comment: yeah you are right but i could never understand how to validate email addresses :)

Comment: can i use the regex written on this page ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301769/jquery-email-validation-requirements

Comment: @tvanfosson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498107/iterating-through-json-object-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-me