# Iterating through json object doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

From a previous question on Stackoverflow [Iterating through/Parsing JSON Object via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637334/iterating-through-parsing-json-object-via-javascript)....

My json object doesn't seem get parsed....
here is my function

```
function Iteratejsondata(HfJsonValue)
{
    var jsonObj = eval('(' + HfJsonValue + ')');
    for (var i = 0, len = HfJsonValue.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var employee = HfJsonValue[i];
        document.write(employee.Emp_Name);
    }
}
```

`employee.Emp_Name` is undefined but when i give
`document.write(employee);` i get this

`{"Table" : [{"Emp_Id" : "3","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Jerome","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Supervisior","Desig_Description" : "Supervisior of the Construction","SalaryBasis" : "Monthly","FixedSalary" : "25000.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "4","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Mohan","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Acc ","Desig_Description" : "Accountant","SalaryBasis" : "Monthly","FixedSalary" : "200.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "5","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Murugan","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Mason","Desig_Description" : "Mason","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "150.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "6","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Ram","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Mason","Desig_Description" : "Mason","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "120.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "7","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Raja","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Mason","Desig_Description" : "Mason","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "135.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "8","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Raja kumar","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Mason Helper","Desig_Description" : "Mason Helper","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "105.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "9","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Lakshmi","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Mason Helper","Desig_Description" : "Mason Helper","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "100.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "10","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Palani","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Carpenter","Desig_Description" : "Carpenter","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "200.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "11","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Annamalai","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Carpenter","Desig_Description" : "Carpenter","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "220.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "12","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "David","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Steel Fixer","Desig_Description" : "Steel Fixer","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "220.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "13","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Chandru","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Steel Fixer","Desig_Description" : "Steel Fixer","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "220.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "14","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Mani","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Steel Helper","Desig_Description" : "Steel Helper","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "175.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "15","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Karthik","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Wood Fixer","Desig_Description" : "Wood Fixer","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "195.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "16","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Bala","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Wood Fixer","Desig_Description" : "Wood Fixer","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "185.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "17","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Tamil arasi","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Wood Helper","Desig_Description" : "Wood Helper","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "185.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "18","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Perumal","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Cook","Desig_Description" : "Cook","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "105.00"},{"Emp_Id" : "19","Identity_No" : "","Emp_Name" : "Andiappan","Address" : "Madurai","Date_Of_Birth" : "","Desig_Name" : "Watchman","Desig_Description" : "Watchman","SalaryBasis" : "Weekly","FixedSalary" : "150.00"}]}`

Any suggestion how to get this done...

**EDIT:**

How add the results to a div...

here is my div

```
<div id="ResultsDiv" class="resultsdiv">
<br />
<span id="EmployeeName" style="font-size:125%;font-weight:bolder;">Pandiyan</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>Supervisor</span><br /><br />
<span id="SalaryBasis" style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>Monthly</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>25,000</span>
<span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>Madurai</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the JavaScript object created by eval().

```
function Iteratejsondata(HfJsonValue) {
  var jsonObj = eval('(' + HfJsonValue + ')');

  for (var i = 0, len = jsonObj.Table.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var employee = jsonObj.Table[i];
    document.write(employee.Emp_Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a templating library to render the data. jTemplates is a good one, for example: http://encosia.com/2008/06/26/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, you can :

1. create the html of your result in a string,
2. then set the content of a div with this string.

How you want your result formatted is up to you, as an example :

```
function Iteratejsondata(HfJsonValue) {
  var jsonObj = eval('(' + HfJsonValue + ')'), str="";

  for (var i = 0, len = jsonObj.Table.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var employee = jsonObj.Table[i];
    str += "<span class='emp'>"+employee.Emp_Name 
         + "</span><span class='sal'>"+employee.FixedSalary
         + "</span><br>";
  }
  $('#WhereIwantMyResults').html(str);
}
```

Comment: @David i want the next div to be exactly the same as parent div with datas being different..